# Split single view horizontally in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3.

I want to edit a single file, but split it horizontally so I can edit two parts of the document (similar to MS Word).

Under view>layout>rows, it shows a file horizontally. However- it only allows a new file (not the same file).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you said you need to split the view by using `View -> Layout - > Rows: 2`. Then being on the Row 1 you need to go to `File -> New View into File`. It will open second tab with the same file. Then you can drag that tab to the Row 2.

Comment: No such thing as "File -> New View into File" in ST4 at this time.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer doesn't work for Using ST4 (build #4126). Here's what I did to **split the same file horizontally**.

1. `View -> Layout -> Rows: 2`. This opens a new empty pane at the bottom.
2. From the top pane (one that currently has the file you want to split), `File -> Split View`. This opens the same file in a new tab.
3. Drag and drop the newly open tab into the bottom pane.

To close the bottom pane, `View -> Layout -> Single`.

Answer (score 0):

Since I’m not reputable, I can’t comment on @abhijit-sarkar.

Anyways, in Sublime Text 4, the "New View into File” menu item as indeed been removed but it’s still available from the Command Palette <kbd>Command/Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

Comment: you can suggest an edit to their post isntead.

Comment: @starball, thanks for that, I was not aware of that feature. Unfortunately, I get 'There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow. Please try again later.’ I will effectively try later.